# How to pull data from News River API into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr, feed, jsonlite

Trying to pull data from the NewsRiver API into R. Specifically would like to convert the json provided into a dataframe for further analysis. I would also like to be able to input my own search terms and domain I would like to search from as variables.

https://newsriver.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))

search_1 <- "Amazon"
search_2 <- "World Domination"
website <- "bloomberg.com"


url <- sprintf('https://api.newsriver.io/v2/search?query=text%%3A%s%%20OR%%20text%%3A%s%%20OR%%20website.domainName%%3A%s%%20OR%%20language%%3AEN&sortBy=_score&sortOrder=DESC&limit=100', search_1, search_2, website)
api_key <- "mykey"

news <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste(api_key, sep = "")))
news_txt <- content(news, as = "text")
news_china_df <- fromJSON(news_txt)
```